# How to speedup WordPress Admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, buddypress

I have a site on WordPress after installing WooCommerce the admin area became much slower. There are more than 100 plugins and around 3000 posts. I have done lots of effort but not get 100% result. Buddypress theme use in it.
I have increased execution time optimize JS and CSS. Frontend response much better than backend. I have to decrease load time of admin panel.

Comment: Have you tried any of these suggestions?  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166727/how-can-i-speed-up-my-wp-admin-section

Comment: yes i did it but still response time more than 30 sec.

Comment: 100 plugins? I think that's way too much. Try to remove the unused plugins.

Comment: yes i know actually client is conscious about each plugin and i have just speedup admin pannel

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the request for api from the WooCommerce site, which can be solved by adding the following filters. Tested in wp version 6.0.3

```
add_filter('pre_transient_wc_onboarding_themes', function ($flag, $transient) {

    return true;
}, 10, 2);

add_filter('pre_transient_wc_onboarding_product_data', function ($flag, $transient) {

    return ["fa_IR" => ["body"=>"{}"]];
}, 10, 2);

add_filter('woocommerce_admin_onboarding_themes', function ($themes) {

   if(!is_array($themes))
   {
    $themes=[];
   }
   return $themes;
}, 10, 2);
```

That in the above code fa_IR is local wordpress.

By adding the above filters, the speed increases a lot